# Mongodb port 27017 not connecting

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

For some reason, I can't link my SSH to my instance of MongoDB, even though I'm on the right port number. [This is a picture of what it's showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg82v.png) It still says "waiting for connection" even though my shell is running.

I've been trying to install/connect to mongoDB for the last three hours and am extremely frustrated. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots use formatted text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: try to debug with ```curl -v telnet://127.0.0.1:27017``` and provide more information

Comment: The mongod service is running and you are successfully connected. What else do you expect?